# Incorrect result of Number.MIN_VALUE - 1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(Number.MIN_VALUE);  // 5e-324
console.log(Number.MIN_VALUE - 1); // -1
```

Value of `Number.MIN_VALUE` is `5e-324`, but if I subtract 1 from it, `-1` is returned.

It looks like some garbage value but I'm wondering why JavaScript interpreter cannot represent it. Otherwise, `Number.MAX_VALUE + 1` is same with `Number.MAX_VALUE(1.7976931348623157e+308)`.

Is there something different between calculating `Numbers.MAX_VALUE` and `Numbers.MIN_VALUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number.MIN_VALUE - 1` is equal to `-0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`

I think any reasonable person would consider that to be `-1`, even before accounting for things like floating point inaccuracy :)

To be clear, `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest value *greater than zero* that can be represented. It is not "negative `Number.MAX_VALUE`" as you appear to expect.

Comment: Shouldn't that last digit be a 5?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Honestly I have no idea - probably, but the exact value is going to have 15 significant digits after all the 9s... Oops.